# angular.js e2e test and $timeout issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple service for displaying flash messages https://github.com/lucassus/mongo_browser/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/app/services.js.coffee#L31 and I'm trying to test it in e2e specs https://github.com/lucassus/mongo_browser/blob/master/spec/javascripts/e2e/databases_scenario.js.coffee#L66
I use $timeout service to hide a flash message after 3 seconds.

I noticed that e2e scenario runner blocks until the timeout flushes and I'm not able to check whether the flash message has been shown.

How to test features with $timeout in e2e specs? 
Is it possible to test this kind of behavior without injecting mock services into the real application?

Comment: I figured out how to do it: https://github.com/lucassus/mongo_browser/blob/master/app/views/index.erb#L44 simply in the `test` mode I'm injecting a service without a timeout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a way to call `inject()` in the end-to-end tests, as described by @christian-smith; this method is for the standard Jasmine tests, not the e2e test runner.

I've created a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Wa7GNoFaxWB5xLlRRnER) to demonstrate.

In the example, the call to `$timeout(halfHourAction, 30*1000, false);` in `app.js` means the tests don't start running for 30 seconds.

In my Real World® example, I'm actually polling something every 30minutes, so the app never starts running at all. Even being able to flush the `$browser`s queue would only add another method to it.

Comment: I don't really think that that's an answer. I think it's more of highlighting the question, and why the other answer won't solve every problem (or any problem in fact).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sleep(seconds)` to make the test wait until your $timeout code has finished. See the API section on this page in the documentation: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.e2e-testing

Also, [$timeout](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24timeout) has a `flush()` method you might find helpful. Just inject $timeout into your test and call flush before any assertions.

Comment: In my opinion doing `sleep` in integration specs is very bad idea.

Comment: How can `$timeout` be injected into a protractor testcase?

Answer (score 1):

We had similar problem with $timeout - our app had to do an XHR every 5 mins - so we had a function that set a re-occurring $timeout every 5mins. This broke our e2e tests, as they were waiting for angular to finish its work before continuing, which never happened.

Heres my workaround to this problem:

- The timeout value was moved as a configuration, which was then mocked - in the real version of our app, the value comes from the backend, in the test-version of our app, we used ngMockE2E to mock the timeout value.
- In the test mock, the interval for the timeout was set to 0ms.
- In the function that sets the $timeout, we have added a normal javascript setTimeout(..., 1000) which wait for 1s before setting a new $timeout.

This way, there is 1s interval between calling $timeout. When e2e tests are run, every 1s a new $timeout (0ms) is added which executes immediately and the tests continue. This has ~ 0 impact to the performance of our e2e tests and is working pretty good for now.